# Alt gr not working on rdp

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v, remote-desktop, keyboard-shortcuts

we use windows 7 on hyperv 2012 r2 if I can connect to virtual pc via console, I can use <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>altgr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> button combination.

however, I can't use these combination when I connect to device via rdp

I checked keyboard layout but i can't see any wrong thing.

how can resolve this problem?

Comment: Maybe it's the same issue as [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926934). You could try using CTRL+ALT instead of the ALTGR key. (Or apply the other workaround in that article)

Comment: yes i tried ctrl+alt and its running. however, The user want to use altgr key.

Comment: Did you try the other workaround in that link? Creating a new shortcut for the connection and in the setting doing `In the Apply Windows key combinations list, click On the local computer` and using that shortcut to connect. Does the AltGr-key work in that case?

Comment: Do the user also want Ctrl-Alt-Del to be forwarded to the remote system? Could it be, that the erroring component here is the user? ;)